# Camera do Game Maker não funciona depois da atualização

Tags: gml

Eu estou fazendo um jogo estilo The Legend Of Zelda no Game Maker Studio 2 mas eu acabei formatando o pc e quando instalei o GMS2 de novo um erro começou a aparecer no Objeto Câmera que estava funcionando corretamente antes e sem problemas, eu tentei olhar o meu código onde o Game Maker apontava ter um erro mas o código esta certo, no meu ponto de vista não parecia ter erros

**Step Event**

```
if (object_exists(follow)){
CamTargetX = follow.x;
CamTargetY = follow.y;

}

x+=(CamTargetX - x)/CamSpd;
y+=(CamTargetY - y)/CamSpd;

camera_set_view_pos(cam, x-w_half, y-h_half);
```

**Create**

```
    cam = view_camera[0];
follow = obj_player
w_half = camera_get_view_width(cam) / 2;
h_half = camera_get_view_height(cam) / 2;
CamTargetX = xstart;
CamTargetY = ystart;
CamSpd = 25;
```

[image: É este erro que aparece, mas para mim o código parece estar certo]

**EDIT**

Eu tentei olhar o index linha 24 mas o Ob_camera não chega ate a linha 24 ate olhei o código do Obj_Player mas a linha 24 é apenas um comando para trocar o Sprite dependendo da direção que o jogador esta se movendo.

Comment: em qual linha da erro? para um erro de index inválido num array "index 24"

Comment: No objeto câmera em especifico não vai ate a linha 24 mas tentei olhar o obj_player e na linha 24 dele não tem muita coisa apenas tem um código para a direção do Sprite mudar dependendo de qual direção ele esta andando

Comment: No evento Step, você já tentou trocar o `object_exists(follow)` por `instance_exists(follow)`? Pelo erro, parece que a instância do objeto "index 24" não existe mais.

Comment: Consegui Resolver Obrigado :D